# Search Results Title Different on Mobile than Desktop

Tags: wordpress, mobile, seo, google-search

I'm having a very weird issue with a site I'm doing a little bit of SEO work for. I've never seen this and can't find another instance of it anywhere so am having trouble resolving it.

If you Google 'FitBeatz' on desktop, you'll see the site show up first in the search results. The title is "FitBeatz : 'Music That Motivates'". If you Google 'FitBeatz' on mobile, the title on the first result shows up as 'First'.

I'm not sure why that's showing up. It is a WordPress site and I use the Yoast SEO plugin but there is no instance of the word 'First' in any of the titles. I've gone to the homepage, viewed the source code and searched for 'First' and nothing shows up so it's not in the meta tags (or anywhere else for that matter).

Why would those results differ? I have no leads at this point and can't seem to find any documentation on this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes search engines use the [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/) title and description. Could that be happening?

Comment: @henrywright, I'm not seeing much documentation on that. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I haven't see any different. Both titles are same on Desktop and mobile. Please check again.